# Node.js : Communication between two servers (net)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I need help about the communication between two servers using 'net' library.
I have two servers process : a master and a slave. The goal is : when the master server down, the slave get up and continue the job.

Well, this is my code :

```
    // MASTER
    var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
        conn.on("error", function() {
        });
    });
    server.listen(61337, "localhost", function () {});

    // SLAVE
    var socket = new net.Socket();
    socket.connect(61337, "localhost", function () {
    });
    socket.on('error', function (exc) {
        if((""+exc) == "Error: read ECONNRESET") {
            console.log("ALERT : MASTER is down !");
        }
    });
```

How can i do to send a message MASTER -> SLAVE ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cluster module (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to create a master-slave logic.

Basically your first process should be the master and the child(ren) could be the slave(s); then children could for example ask the master his status every minutes; If this one does not reply, it means the master process is down and at that moment you can do any logic you would like to.

You can use `worker.send(msg)` and `process.send(msg)` and make them respectively listen the `message` event to deal with response.

```
process|worker.on('message', function(msg) {
    // Code logic
});
```